# C# JsonSerializer.Serialize missing files

Tags: c#, json, system.text.json

I am trying to serialize a List of MapPools but every time I seem to get an error about missing files. As you can see I added the dependencie System.Text.Json.

This is the code I have for it but it quits JsonSerializer.Serialize. Any ideas on how to fix the missing files?
Thanks

```
private const string MapPoolsFile = @"../../../resources/MapPools.json";
public void JSONSerializerMapPools()
        {
            if (File.Exists(MapPoolsFile))
            {
                List<Map> Maps = new List<Map> { new Map(Side.Attack, Side.Deffend, "Inferno"), new Map(Side.Attack, Side.Deffend, "Nuke"), new Map(Side.Attack, Side.Deffend, "Mirage") };
                List<MapPool> MapPools = new List<MapPool> { new MapPool("CSGO BIG3", Maps) };
                string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(MapPools);
                Console.WriteLine(json);
                File.WriteAllText(MapPoolsFile, json);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File not found");
            }
                
        }
```

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Memory, Version=4.0.1.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions.GetDefaultSimpleConverters()
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions.RootBuiltInConverters()
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions.InitializeForReflectionSerializer()
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.GetTypeInfo(JsonSerializerOptions options, Type runtimeType)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize[TValue](TValue value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
   at Datalaag.DataProvider.JSONSerializerMapPools()
```

Comment: Can you share the exception and stacktrace please?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! if you haven't you should check [ask] and provide [mcve] of your problem. also,  what is the content of `MapPoolsFile`? does the file exists? do you have write permission on it?

Comment: @BagusTesa The MapPoolsFile is an empty json file. And I should have write persmission for it.

Comment: @JamesGould I just added it

Comment: The exception looks to be choking on a `System.Memory` call/dependency?

Comment: @DSMTurboAWD It was indeed missing this dependency so I added it and it resolved my problem. I don't know why it didn't try this earlier. Thanks a a lot!